# Display data member in group header template in Kendo UI Grid ASP.NET MVC

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a member that I want to display other member from data in group header. Look at below code:

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid<MailModel>()
...
.Columns(c=>
{
  ...
  c.Bound(b=> b.ReceivedDate).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#:data.ReceivedDateStandard#");
  ...
})
.DataSource(ds=> ds
  .Ajax()
  .Group(g=>g.Add(i=>i.ReceivedDate))
);
```

Everything work great, but the **group header text is "undefined"!!!**

How can I show another member data in group header text?

Thanks for fallowing.....

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible.
Logically, when you are grouping, the only members that you have available are the members that you are grouping by and the aggregates of that group.
Unless you can group by both ReceivedDate and ReceivedDateStandard or calculate ReceivedDateStandard from ReceivedDate then you wont be able to show ReceivedDateStandard  in the group header.

Comment: I just did something like your answer. pass the "ReceivedDate" to function, search in my data, find the row and return "ReceivedDateStandard". But I think it's not the good way. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

for anyone with problem binding to the current value but with custom template, use this binding:
`#:value#`
instead of 
`#:data.FieldName#`